# Submitted app to appstore with adhoc profile

Tags: distribution, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I submitted a new app to the app store today. The upload was accepted by Apple so I assume everything is correct. But I had a thought. Take a look at the screenshot I've attached, the distribution profile I used, the method is set to 'Ad-Hoc' (I was using that profile to send builds to the client). Should that be set to 'Distribution' instead? I'm afraid the app might get rejected if it's set to adhoc.

Should I leave it set to adhoc, or change it to distribution? Will it be a problem?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You answered that it wasn't a problem - does it mean that it worked on all the devices, or just on the devices that you set for this ad hoc version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case anyone faces this situation, the app was accepted by Apple and is available on the app store. I am however going to submit an update with a release distribution to be sure that everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks, just made the same mistake myself so this is reassuring.

Comment: Most important question is did the version, which is code-signed and uploaded with adhoc distribution profile, working on all the devices? I mean all other than the devices nominated in the profile?

Comment: @Ahmed what is the answer to your question?

Comment: @Ahmed, did it work? Was the adhoc-signed IPA successfully distributed through Appstore? I know 2 years have passed, really wishing this wasn't closed.

Comment: It was so long ago I forgot what happened! I have a vague recollection I rejected the binary before release and re-signed and re-uploaded with distribution profile, so I can't answer wether it worked for all devices or just the signed one.