# Submitting Ad-hoc app to Appstore / iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, code-signing, ad-hoc-distribution, application-loader

I ***know*** how to sign an app with Appstore mobile provision, and how to re-sign an Adhoc-signed IPA with Appstore mobile provision. This is not my question.

My question is, can you ***submit*** Adhoc-signed IPA to Appstore / iTunesConnect, and have it pass Apple verification and eventually be distributed through Appstore. Why? So that I don't have to store a redundant Appstore-signed IPA along every Adhoc-signed release candidate IPA, and don't have to do the extra step of re-signing that requires a Mac machine.

When using **Application Loader**, it is able to find all the stupid little errors, like missing icons and launch images, but even when I upload Adhoc-signed IPA through Application Loader, **it doesn't complain about non-appstore mobile provision** (which is very easy to verify, just like icons).

I have also found out in my testing, that when you take an Appstore-signed IPA (which you are not supposed to be able to install on devices unless distributed through Appstore), it is possible to install it on testing devices, provided the device already has Adhoc provision profile on it (same AppID, same distribution cert).

So, this makes me think Apple just strips out mobile provision when distributing through Appstore.

There was a similar question (closed) from almost 3 years ago, but the OP never provided an answer if it had actually worked:  **[Submitted app to appstore with adhoc profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143826/submitted-app-to-appstore-with-adhoc-profile)**.

I hope someone since then had actually tried with it confirmed results.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a few targeted inner questions within your main question, I'll call attention to each part as we go -- as always, I'll be happy to revise or clarify if I miss something.  I suppose it is only a closely guarded secret because much of the reasoning for it working come back to cryptographic details as a function of the Public Key Infrastructure system that backs Apple's provisioning -- This stuff gets deep fast so it is considered by some to be [dark] magic.  Hopefully this will shine some light on what is going on!

**TL;DR Version**

Yes you can, but it is technically an unsupported use case that may change at any time.  This works because what information iTunes Connect chooses to validate does not include the single differentiating factor between an App Store and AdHoc distribution provisioning profile.  Since this is technically not a permitted configuration, I'd advocate for at least having a backup plan since Apple may change iTunes Connect validation policy at any time breaking this submission edge case.

**Now for the curious, the here is the rest of the story...**

*Can you submit Adhoc-signed IPA to Appstore / iTunesConnect, and have it pass Apple verification and eventually be distributed through Appstore[?]*

As of this specific iteration of iTunesConnect and the Application Loader (4 Sept 2014 / Xcode 5.1.1), yes you can submit an AdHoc signed build and have it accepted through the pipeline.  The eagle-eyed reader will note that my 'Yes' comes with a built-in escape hatch -- Because of the data encoded in AdHoc vs App Store provisioning profiles is nearly identical coupled with what parts of these files iTunesConnect is actually using for validation, an AdHoc provisioning profile presents to the delivery pipeline in the same manner as the AppStore version of the same app.

Should the provisioning format change between AdHoc and App Store files to explicitly differentiate the two types of Distribution provisioning profiles or should Apple iTunesConnect engineers change server-side validation rules, it is distinctly possible that this undocumented behavior will stop working.  Of course we all know that we are **supposed** to use the App Store provisioning profile, as per Developer documentation in the App Distribution Guide > Submitting Your App > About Store Provisioning Profiles (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW32) [emphasis added]:

> A store distribution provisioning profile contains a single App ID that matches one or more of your apps, and a distribution certificate. **For iOS apps, you need a store provisioning profile to submit your app.**

...but this other avenue works for now.  If you do choose to use this avenue, you just need to be aware that it is not the documented behavior and thus would be subject to change at any point in time, likely without advanced notice.  Since it is skirting the edges of submission requirements it would probably be good to at least have a backup plan setup for the case of Apple changing provisioning or iTC validation requirements -- Murphy's law would dictate that these validation changes would happen at the most inopportune time.

Stepping off the 'Best Practice' Soapbox and turning to the technical side of things...

*Why [does this work]?*

As you may or may not know, provisioning profiles are composed of exactly 1 appId, one or more signing certificates, and zero or more test devices.

**Related Reading**: I've got a longer answer to [What are code signing identities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996468/what-are-code-signing-identities/16070915#16070915) that speaks in more detail to the parts of the codesign process.

In this case the question is 'why do AdHoc profiles work when the documentation says you need to have an App Store profile?'

The guts of a provisioning profile contain a cryptographically signed .plist that includes the information identified above, plus some additional metadata.  On an OS X machine you can open Terminal and run:

`security cms -D -i path/to/AdHoc.mobileprovision`

...and in a separate Terminal window run the App Store profile equivalent:

`security cms -D -i path/to/AppStore.mobileprovison`

These commands will dump out the plist portion of the provisioning profile to their respective Terminal windows.  When you scroll through the contents of both windows you will note that the following sections are identical:

- AppIDName
- AppliationIdentifierPrefix
- DeveloperCertificates
- Entitlements
- TeamIdentifier
- Version

The profile's metadata are different, but those are entirely expected differences that only matter for validating profile validity, or for humans interrogating the profile:

- CreationDate
- ExpirationDate
- Name
- TimeToLive
- UUID

The salient points to take away are:

- The `DeveloperCertificates` blocks are **identical** between both profiles.
- The AdHoc profile only **adds** information (`ProvisionedDevices`) to the structure and format of the App Store profile.

The contents of the `DeveloperCertificates` array is the DER encoded X.509 iPhone Distribution Certificate -- The exact same as the one in your keychain.  Is is important to note that this DER data is only the public portion of your **Distribution** certificate public-private keypair, and it can only be used by others to authenticate the application's signature came from you -- It can not be used to resign a binary as you.

If you paste the contents of DeveloperCertificates:Array:Data element into an ASN.1 decoder (http://lapo.it/asn1js/) and compare the elements of the output to the information encoded in the Distribution certificate included in the Keychain, you'll find that it is an exact copy of the public **Distribution** certificate you downloaded from Apple after submitting your Certificate Signing Request though the Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles tool.

Because both the AdHoc and App Store provisioning profiles use the same public key certificate as their signing identity, they are inherently using the same private key when generating the application's signature.  **This means that the signature generated when signing with an AdHoc profile is functionally identical to one generated when signing with the App Store profile**

When Apple performs a signature validation on iTunes Connect during the submission process, both and AdHoc signed cryptographic signature and an App Store signed cryptographic signature will successfully validate against the Distribution Certificate Apple has on file as both provisioning profiles are backed by the same Distribution Certificate.

**So the signatures match, but why doesn't the extra information in AdHoc profiles trip up the submission?**

Your original question suggests that you have familiarity with iOS' app install policies.  For the benefit of someone stumbling across this answer in the future I'll briefly summarize:

iOS operates on a 'deny-all unless specifically permitted' policy.  That is, iOS assumes you are not allowed to install an app unless a specific 'grant' has been allowed.  For devices coming from the App Store, the app's signature includes Apple's App Store identity for which iOS has a specific 'grant' privilege.  AdHoc installs by default fall under the 'deny' policy and the `ProvisionedDevices` section of a *Development* or *AdHoc* profile are the specific 'grant' privileges.  The app will install outside of the App Store if all of the following hold true:

- The application's cryptographic signature is valid
- The application's embedded provisioning profile's cryptographic signature is still valid (the profile hasn't been tampered with)
- The application's embedded provisioning profile's `ExpirationDate` hasn't passed and the current time isn't before the `CreationDate`
- The embedded profile or a profile installed to the device match the AppId being proposed for installation.
- The embedded profile or a profile installed to the device contain an entry in `ProvisionedDevices` that exactly match the device's UDID.

As we saw above, the app identity and signing information is identical between an App Store profile and and Ad Hoc profile -- the addition of `ProvisionedDevices` serves only to add these 'grant' privileges for an external (outside of App Store) distribution mechanism.  It turns out that iTunes Connect / Application Loader validation is currently only validating that a *Distribution* profile was used for the app's signature, not that the profile that was used was an App Store profile instead of an AdHoc profile.

This boils down to the fact that the as of Version 1 (ala `Version` block in the plist) the only differentiating factor between AdHoc and App Store distribution profiles is the presence or absence of the `ProvisionedDevices` block.  It turns out that as of today, this *is not* a detail that Apple looks for when interrogating the profile that was used, thus the binary passes the automated portions of app verification.  They definitely do check that the AppId in the profile matches what the App claims, that the signing identity matches what was used to sign the binary, expiration dates, and any entitlements used match what is found in the automated scan of the app, in addition to the items you highlighted in your original question (version checks between iTunes Connect and the info.plist, iconography presence, iconography sizes, etc.)

Hypothetically, in a subsequent iTunes Connect / Application Loader update, they could start checking for the **absence** of this key in the `embedded.mobileprovision` profile that exists within the submitted binary and auto-reject the submission on the grounds that an App Store profile was not used.  Similarly, if the provisioning profile format was updated (ex. Version=2) they could add a new element that explicitly calls out the type of profile and auto-reject if it isn't an App Store type.  It could perhaps look like this:

```
<key>ProfileType</key>
<integer>1</integer>
```

Where the integer value could be 1, 2 or, 3 depending on the type of profile in use, consistent with the formats used in things like Info.plist for identifying supported device families (iPhone-only, iPad-only, or Universal). This would clarify other questions that have been asked about identifying the type of build.

*Related Reading:*

- [How to detect that a provisioning profile is for development or distribution, programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243855/how-to-detect-that-a-provisioning-profile-is-for-development-or-distribution-pr/16268904#16268904)
- [Check if app is ad-hoc|dev|app-store build at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584426/check-if-app-is-ad-hocdevapp-store-build-at-run-time/17627239#17627239)

*So, this makes me think Apple just strips out mobile provision when distributing through Appstore.*

Yes they do! If you look at archived versions of the apps you submitted you'll find that the contents of the app contain `embedded.mobileprovision` -- if you then go download the same version from the App Store, you'll find that file missing.  Apple only uses embedded.mobileprovision to verify the contents of your app during the submission and review process.  When the app is 'Processing for App Store' the final package is assembled and the embedded profile is removed.

Comment: Brilliant answer. You, sir, get the bounty. Some parts I've suspected, just never had confirmed. Other parts were new for me. Thank you for the time you took to answer a question that most simply refused to understand.

Comment: No problem, happy to share!

Comment: ...aaaaand update: Recall that 'Apple may change things without notice' business I wrote about? Yes? Good. A short while ago, Apple gave iTunes Connect just got a software upgrade that was definitely a visual overhaul, but potentially also an overhaul of the backend systems. It is too soon to say if they've changed validation requirements as my teams have closed up shop for the night, but we should learn more about whats new tomorrow when additional app submissions are made (fingers crossed for only overhauling the UI)

Comment: @BryanMusial Is this still possible in 2018?

Comment: @uloco The provisioning profile formats have not changed since this answer was originally written and the the direct acknowledgement that it is undocumented behavior subject to Apple's whim still very much applies.  My app's CI process differentiate AdHoc and AppStore builds for me, so I've not had need to retest this behavior in years, but if you do give this a shot, leave a note here for others!  Conceptually the same kinds of validations are in place on Apple's side today so I imagine it would still work, but can not say with 100% certainty that is still works the way it had in 2014.