# Is it possible to release app (AppStore) signed with AdHoc profile?

Tags: ios

At the moment during our build i make an IPA file signed with the Distribution certificate and the AppStore profile. I'd like to replace the signing of this IPA with AdHoc so we can distribute this IPA thru Microsoft AppCenter. My question is as following :

*Can i use this new ipa with AdHoc signed on TestFlight External Test AND eventually release this iPA file to the AppStore OR is it a requirement to upload a new binary resigned with the AppStore profile ?*

I could imagine that this would work which means Apple must resign the iPA on the fly to AppStore profile because the iPA is already signed with the Distribution certificate.

/donnib

Comment: You might want to read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571573/submitting-ad-hoc-app-to-appstore-itunesconnect

Answer (score 0):

you can use AdHoc to distribute your app to public but that has limit. few people can use your AdHoc whose  UUID you were added on certificate. AdHoc certificate/profile and Distribution certificate/profile are different.

you can not release AdHoc to appStore or any other store.